# How to get default titlepage with extra pdf-frontpage?

Tags: pdf, titles, front-matter

I want to have normal LaTeX frontpage, then my University's frontpage and then normal content.

My tex

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1} % use prl for onepage
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{multirow}    

\begin{document}     
\title{La la la}
\author{Masi}

\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}    
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}
\end{flushright}

% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={1}]{abstract_1.pdf}
\clearpage

Content here la la la

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

So problems are the wrong looking frontpage and the overflow of the text of the frontpage to the next page.
It should be normal LaTeX one with big title in the center of the page and below it texts.

The texts which I have now in **\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}** goes on the top of the pdf-page which is wrong.

**How can you have the default LaTeX frontpage?**

**Why is the content being overflown on the top of the pdf-page?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put `\maketitle` inside the `titlepage` environment to obtain what you want:

[image]

Code (I've also added a `\vfill` before `\today` assuming that you want it at the bottom of the page):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1} % use prl for onepage
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\title{La la la}
\author{Masi}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}
\end{flushright}

% Bottom of the page
\vfill
{\large \today}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={1}]{abstract_1.pdf}
\clearpage

Content here la la la

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I extended my problem here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148007/to-have-two-names-side-by-side-in-titlepage I want also Big title in the center of the page. **Do you know how to achieve it?**

Comment: @Masi Do you mean something like `\title{\Huge{La la la}}`?

Comment: It is better, but I think there exists default titlepage in Latex where you have title in the very center of the page. I do not remember how to get it.

Comment: `\maketitle` inside a titlepage environment? This is a bad example for newbies ;-)