# To have two names side by side in titlepage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

My tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle

\begin{flushright} \large
\begin{align}
\emph{Supervisor:} & \emph{Intsructor:} \\
Prof. Sami &  M.Sc. Tech. Henri
\end{align}
\end{flushright}


% Bottom of the page
\vfill
{\large \today}
\end{titlepage}
```

I get

[image]

where is no align.

**How can you get aligns there such that Supervisor is on the left-hand-side and Instructor on the right-hand-side?**

Comment: Don't use `align` for aligning text. `align` is for math. Use a table.

Comment: @zeroth You can also use minipages

Comment: @Kartik, sure, but a `tabular` is a non-float object and then you don't need to specify sizes of the block. In my opinion much easier, at least to maintain. :)

Comment: @zeroth `minipage` doesn't flow, but it is what it says it it, a `page` on its own, a bit more proper would be `\parbox`. However, I agree that `tabular` is the right choice here.

Comment: @tohecz, I didn't say that minipage was a float, I can now see that it could be implied from my comment. It was a general comment. I just saw no reason for anything other than a `tabular`.

Comment: Actually the same thing is described in LaTeX wikibooks with minipages. Here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be also done with the `tabbing environment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabbing}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{7em} \= \\ %defines length of first tabular with \hspace
Supervisor: \> Instructor: \\
Prof. Sami \> M.Sc. Tecg. Henri \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{15em} \= \\ % increased the length to 15em
Supervisor: \> Instructor: \\
Prof. Sami \> M.Sc. Tecg. Henri \\
\end{tabbing}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{15em} \= \\
Supervisor: \> Instructor: \\
Prof. Sami Sami Sami Sami Sami \> M.Sc. Tecg. Henri \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some bug here when you have long name: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-02%20at%2019.06.36.png Names are over each other. I tried to solve it by having two tabs by **\>\>** but it gives an error.

Comment: Edited it with some commentary. You set the length of the first tab with the \hspace{length} command. If you have 3 tabs you would have to define the length for the second also and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do something like this (if you wanted Instructor right-aligned use `{lr}` in the tabular definition):

```
\begin{flushright} \large
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\emph{Supervisor:} & \emph{Instructor:} \\
Prof. Sami &  M.Sc. Tech. Henri
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\emph{Supervisor:} & Prof. Sami \\
\emph{Instructor:} & M.Sc. Tech. Henri
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\emph{Supervisor} & : & Prof. Sami \\
\emph{Instructor} & : & M.Sc. Tech. Henri
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
```

Which yields:

[image]

You can always play with the spacing between columns to get the wanted spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Align is used for mathematical equations. This is not a mathematical equation. You should not use the align environment here. You can try to do this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
{\large
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\emph{Supervisor:}
Prof. Sami
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\emph{Instructor:}
M.Sc. Tech. Henri
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: There is some compiling errors in this code.

Comment: @Masi Try it again now. There was some error which has been edited now.